# resolving conflicts in pull request

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a repository on github and a teammate forked it, now he sent me a pull request so what should I do to resolve the conflicts? I am on master branch so what commands should I write?

Comment: resolve the conflicts if any and commit again.

Comment: yes I know but what should I do to resolve conflicts?

Comment: when you pulled you should see the file list with conflicts. Open them in your editor and if the editor supports merge conflicts then do it that way else you have to do it manually. When you open the files you will see the code markings.

Comment: Please see this https://www.grandcircus.co/blog/resolving-git-conflicts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [gh CLI (command Line Interface) for GitHub](https://cli.github.com/)

That allows you to merge it directly: [`gh pr merge xxx`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_merge)

If there is any merge conflict, the merge will fail.

At this point, you can checkout locally the PR branch: [gh pr checkout xxx](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_checkout)

Then merge the local pr branch to your target branch (`master`):

```
git switch master
git merge patch-x
```

Resolve any conflict (see [GitHub tutorial](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line) or [OReilly](https://www.oreilly.com/content/how-do-i-fix-a-merge-conflict-in-git/)), and push the result to your remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

please following below step::

- **git branch** ,

  **git checkout branchname**,

  **git switch master**,

  **git merge patch-x**,

Comment: Yes, but how do you get the patch-x branch? That is what my answer details.

Comment: @git branch checkout and you get branch

Comment: Indeed, although these day, you would use git switch, not git checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309